# How to use my earphone button?

Tags: vlc

Good evening guys 
I want to use my earphone button to pause/play videos and musics on VLC media player ... i have tried to do it from preferences --> hotkeys doesn't work
Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wired **earphone button** has 4 leads on the male plug which works ok on smartphones that have 4 receptors on the female jack. However most laptops only have 3 receptors on the female jack so the button can't operate.

If you have bluetooth earbuds this link ([Bluetooth headset multimedia buttons])[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Headset.27s_multimedia_buttons) would help you out. Basically it says `/etc/modules-load.d/uinput.conf` needs to contain `uinput`.

Comment: @Random if the answer is acceptable mark it as the solution (and up vote it if it's helpful) so others know it is right. If the answer doesn't make sense or needs clarification please leave a comment so it can be improved for you and others that follow.

Comment: i don't know if the answer is 100% correct so i will make some researches

Comment: @Random If you discover a better answer you can post it yourself and then mark it as the solution 2 days later. Thanks for commenting back.

Comment: I didn't find anything better
Thank you